# Does the Eladrin Soldier feat grant Greatspear proficiency?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, weapons

Does the Eladrin soldier feat gives proficiency with the Greatspear? It says:

> You gain proficiency with all spears and a +2 feat bonus to damage rolls with longswords and all spears.

The Greatspear is a Superior weapon though:

> **Superior Weapon:** Superior weapons are even more effective than military weapons but require special training to use. You can learn to use a superior weapon by taking the Weapon Proficiency feat.

Some people say that, because it is a superior weapon, you need the Weapon Proficiency feat to be proficient with a Greatspear, even if you have the Eladrin soldier feat.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. All means All.

This is the same wording that is used on the Dwarven Weapon Training feat, and that is regularly used to give Dwarves Craghammers and Mordenkrads.

That said, some DMs may not allow these feats to grant proficiency with superior weapons; ruling that they were not intended to provide it based on the fact that the superior weapons they grant were published later. This doesn't hold much water, but make sure that the standard ruling that these weapon proficiencies are provided holds true at your table.

The proper counterargument if your DM makes this one is that WOTC had *ample* opportunity to errata these feats and did not. That said, if he wants to make a stink about it, just move on.

Comment: Supporting evidence: The DDI character builder includes Greatspear, Gouge, and Zadatl in "suggested items" when selecting equipment, and includes proficiency w/Greatspear and Eladrin Soldier damage bonus on powers.